# How to efficiently collapse recurrent columns into rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance

The objective is to collapse a `df` with the following columns

```
['ID', 'St ti', 'Comp time', 'Email', 'Name', 'Gr Name\n',
   'As Na (P1)\n', 'Fr ID (P1)\n', '        Role   & royce ', 'Cradle insigt', 'Co-exist network', 'Ample Tree (P1)\n',
   'As Na (P2)\n', 'Fr ID (P2)\n', '        Role   & royce 2', 'Cradle insigt2', 'Co-exist network2', 'Ample Tree (P2)\n',
   'As Na (P3)\n', 'Fr ID (P3)\n', '        Role   & royce 3', 'Cradle insigt3', 'Co-exist network3', 'Ample Tree (P3)\n']
```

into

```
['id','st_ti','comp_ti','email','name','gr_na','as_na',
          'fr_id','role_royce','cradle_insight',
          'coexist_net','ample_tree']
```

The original `df` columns contain common naming but are differentiated by unique numbering.

For example, the common name is as below

```
'As Na', 'Fr ID', '        Role   & royce ', 'Cradle insigt', 'Co-exist network', 'Ample Tree'
```

whereas the unique numbering is as below

```
'As Na (P1)\n','As Na (P2)\n','As Na (P3)\n'
```

Therefore, for a `df` as below,

```
   ID  St ti  Comp time  ...  Cradle insigt3  Co-exist network3  Ample Tree (P3)\n
0   4      0          3  ...               0                  3                  0
1   2      3          0  ...               4                  0                  4
2   1      4          1  ...               4                  4                  4

[3 rows x 24 columns]
```

The collapsing operation should yield the following output

```
 id  st_ti  comp_ti  ...  cradle_insight  coexist_net  ample_tree
0   4      0        3  ...               0            0           4
1   2      3        0  ...               1            1           0
2   1      4        1  ...               1            3           3
3   4      0        3  ...               1            1           0
4   2      3        0  ...               3            2           4
5   1      4        1  ...               3            4           1
6   4      0        3  ...               0            3           0
7   2      3        0  ...               4            0           4
8   1      4        1  ...               4            4           4

[9 rows x 12 columns]
```

The above objective can be completed using the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)


cosl_ori=['ID', 'St ti', 'Comp time', 'Email', 'Name', 'Gr Name\n',
   'As Na (P1)\n', 'Fr ID (P1)\n', '        Role   & royce ', 'Cradle insigt', 'Co-exist network', 'Ample Tree (P1)\n',
   'As Na (P2)\n', 'Fr ID (P2)\n', '        Role   & royce 2', 'Cradle insigt2', 'Co-exist network2', 'Ample Tree (P2)\n',
   'As Na (P3)\n', 'Fr ID (P3)\n', '        Role   & royce 3', 'Cradle insigt3', 'Co-exist network3', 'Ample Tree (P3)\n']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 24)),
                  columns=cosl_ori)
cols=df.columns.tolist()
indices_s = [i for i, s in enumerate(cols) if 'As Na' in s]

indices_e = [i for i, s in enumerate(cols) if 'Ample Tree' in s]

indices_e=[x.__add__(1) for x in indices_e]

col_int=[range(x,y) for x,y in zip(indices_s,indices_e)]
std_col=range(0,6)

col_name=['id','st_ti','comp_ti','email','name','gr_na','as_na',
          'fr_id','role_royce','cradle_insight',
          'coexist_net','ample_tree']
all_df=[]
for dcols in col_int:
    expanded_col=list(std_col)+list(dcols)
    dd=df.iloc[:,expanded_col]
    dd.columns=col_name
    all_df.append(dd)

df_expected_output = pd.concat(all_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

However, I wonder whether there are more elegant ways of addressing the aforementioned objective. Specifically,the code block

```
all_df=[]
    for dcols in col_int:
        expanded_col=list(std_col)+list(dcols)
        dd=df.iloc[:,expanded_col]
        dd.columns=col_name
        all_df.append(dd)
    
    df_expected_output = pd.concat(all_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Apart from that (OPTIONAL), the above solution strictly request the last SIX columns to be in the specific order.

```
['As Na (P1)\n', 'Fr ID (P1)\n', '        Role   & royce ', 'Cradle insigt', 'Co-exist network', 'Ample Tree (P1)\n',
   'As Na (P2)\n', 'Fr ID (P2)\n', '        Role   & royce 2', 'Cradle insigt2', 'Co-exist network2', 'Ample Tree (P2)\n',
   'As Na (P3)\n', 'Fr ID (P3)\n', '        Role   & royce 3', 'Cradle insigt3', 'Co-exist network3', 'Ample Tree (P3)\n']
```

and will fail if some of the columns is shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

Creating Pandas dataframe tends to be pretty slow. Since `df` contains integers, we can use Numpy arrays instead which as significantly faster. Here is a faster implementation:

```py
all_arrays=[]
df_data = df.to_numpy()
for dcols in col_int:
    expanded_col = np.array(list(std_col) + list(dcols), dtype=np.int32)
    all_arrays.append(df_data[:, expanded_col])
df_expected_output = pd.DataFrame(data=np.vstack(all_arrays), columns=col_name)
```

This is **8 times faster** on the example on my machine (~0.1 ms instead of ~0.8 us). 80% of the time is spent in the final `pd.DataFrame` (which is not really reasonable by the way but this is the price to pay for using Pandas). The bigger the input list (`col_int`), the faster this implementation.

Actually, this code works for any kind of `df` values including strings. It is just slower when there are mixed types because the code cannot be really vectorized. Additionally, the output is an object-based dataframe in this case and the type of each column is lost.

One solution to keep the type of the column is to treat them separately. Here is an implementation:

```py
all_arrays = [[] for i in range(12)]
df_cols = [df[col].to_numpy() for col in df.columns]
for dcols in col_int:
    expanded_col = list(std_col) + list(dcols)
    for i in range(12):
        all_arrays[i].append(df_cols[expanded_col[i]])
for i in range(12):
    all_arrays[i] = np.concatenate(all_arrays[i])
df_expected_output2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(col_name, all_arrays)))
```

This is slower: it is only about **2.3 faster** than the initial code. Still, about 75% of the time is spent in the final `pd.DataFrame` call (more than with a uniform Numpy array). The `np.concatenate` can be made faster using Numba for int/float types but there is not much to do so to speed up strings. If you want something fast, you should avoid strings like the plague (eg. like converting string columns to categorial columns when there are only few unique strings)

Comment: Thanks for the elegant proposal, however in the real-world case, the `df` is a mixture of number and string. I should improve the OP to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Ok, sad. This is an important thing to mention since CPython strings objects are generally slow. One can use Numpy arrays of string objects or just Numpy array of native strings if the strings are all approximately of the same size. Is the number of selected columns always known at ahead of time (12) ?

Comment: Yes, the number of selected columns is known ahead of time, as shown in the OP.

Comment: I edited the question to supports mixed-types (which make things inherently slower).